# Errors Installing KeystoneJS on OSX

Tags: node.js, npm, keystonejs

I ran npm install -g generator-keystone from the root directory in OSX but got the following errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
```

When I try and use yo keystone I then get:

```
-bash: yo: command not found
```

I did try and update these packages using:

```
npm update -g minimatch
npm update -g CSSselect
npm update -g CSSwhat
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

(PS I have Node 4.4.3 and Mongo Shell 3.2.7 installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you're getting are warnings, not errors. You can ignore them.

It looks like you may have only installed the Keystone generator for Yeoman, but didn't install the [`yeoman`](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman) package itself:

```
$ npm i yo -g
```

That should provide the `yo` executable (which generally gets installed in `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: That's great thanks. Yeoman didn't work though so I did npm i yo -g instead

Comment: @MattLeach ah yeah, my bad. I'll edit my answer to correct that :)